# Need clarification about some metaphors/slangs used by a girl I met online

Tags: slang, metaphors

Hi I was talking to this girl online and she uses lots of metaphors and slangs out of which few of them just gone over my head so I would appreciate if you guys could help me out understanding the real essense/meaning of that. I will state the context too to give you an idea.
1) I am sooo ready for the heat! (context- this was just the starting of our chat where we both introduced each other and she was quite fascnicated by my profile and pic.)
2) Please tell me out at wash??!! I'm sooo ready!! What about you? Do you work? (Context- This came on the same day chat right after when she told me about her work and asked mine as you can see in the same statement. I didnt get the first two phrases in this statement.)
3) My oven is finally hooked up so I stopped by the store and just finished eating salad. (Context- This was from the later day)
4) wow you are fiesty today!!! (Context- She asked what did I have for lunch, I said food then she replied this)

Thanks
Sid

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's too broad, too opinion-based, and basically not much more than a request for a "translation service".

Comment: I'm not sure about opinion based. You might be closer if you said that this is not English.

Comment: This looks more like a conversation with a chatbot. http://www.personalityforge.com/botfinder.php

Comment: He's asking for interpretation of idioms and slang. That seems well within scope to me.

Comment: You should try posting this on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

These might require more context. But here's my stab:

1. "I am so ready for the heat." This sounds like a literal statement to me. It is winter, she is tired of winter weather, and she is looking forward to warm weather. "Heat" is also American slang for police or other authorities, as in one thief saying to another, "Let's get out of here before the heat arrives!" But that seems unlikely here. Oh, "I am so ready" is an idiom for "I really want", maybe that's the confusing part. "I am so ready for summer" means, I want summer to start now.
2. "Please tell me out at wash?!" I have no idea. This sentence makes no sense to me.
3. "My oven is finally hooked up so I stopped by the store and just finished eating salad." This sounds literal, too. "My oven is finally hooked up" -- she bought a new oven and there was some delay before it could be connected to the electricity or gas lines, but now it finally is connected and usable. "... and just finished eating salad" Umm, she was eating a salad and now she is finished? Maybe she means that now that the oven is working she can eat something besides salad.
4. "wow you are fiesty today!" "Fiesty" is presumably a mis-spelling of "feisty", which is a mild way of saying "you are being annoying or trying to start an argument". That is, if someone contradicted you or gave a non-answer to a question and you were really mad at them, you might say, "You're just trying to start an argument!" But if their non-answer is obviously a joke and everyone is having a good time, you can say, "Oh, you're being feisty". It ranges from going along with the joke to a mild complaint, depending on tone and context. Here, I assume she's laughing along with the joke.

Comment: In the context of what is presumably flirting, feisty can mean something quite different.

Comment: @terdon True, but given his statement that she asked what he had for lunch and he said "food", I think she meant it in the sense I described. But yes, "feisty" can also mean "flirtatious" or, in the right context, "sexually aggressive".

Comment: To be honest, the whole conversation sounds like a teenager trying to be erudite. +1 by the way, I was not trying to imply your interpretation was wrong.

Comment: That chatbot theory also seems plausible.